# How Can I ReWrite flat link to a dynamic link and preserve the Query string?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am wanting to rewrite a url like:
 
http://my.project/mydomain.com/ANY_NUMBER_OF_CATEGORIES/designer/4/designer-name/page.html

to this:
http://my.projects/mydomain.com/ANY_NUMBER_OF_CATEGORIES/page.html?designer=4

I would like to use mod-rewrite to accomplish this.

Things to note:

1. Any number of categories can be between 'mydomain.com/' and '/designer'.

   1. For instance the url could be http://my.project/mydomain.com/designer/4/designer-name/page.html or it could be http://my.project/mydomain.com/tops/shirts/small/designer/4/designer-name/page.html
2. A query string may be provided in the original url that needs to be preserved in the rewritten url.

   1. For example url provided could be: http://my.project/mydomain.com/designer/4/designer-name/page.html?color=red&type=shirt
   2. Given the url above the resulting url would need to be: http://my.projects/mydomain.com/page.html?designer=4&color=red&type=shirt
   3. The order of the query string does not matter. The 'designer=4' part could come before or after the rest of the query string.

I'm new to .htaccess and re-writes so any examples and or explanations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to create two separate RewriteRules:

```
RewriteRule ^designer/([^/]+)/.*/([^/]+)\.html $2.html?designer=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule (.*)/designer/([^/]+)/.*/([^/]+)\.html $1/$3.html?designer=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Thanks to Gumbo for pointing out the [QSA] portion of the rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?(\d+)/[^/]+/([^/]+\.html)$ $1$3?designer=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This looks good and it looks like it almost does it, however the "designer" part of the url stays in the rewrite.
Result----
http://my.project/mydomain.com/designer/4/designer-name/page.html
becomes
http://my.projects/mydomain.com/designer/page.html?designer=4
Though I was hoping it would be:
http://my.projects/mydomain.com/page.html?designer=4

I did do something in my .htaccess file that appears to be working - but being a "noob" I'm not sure how good it is:
RewriteRule ^designer/([^/]+)/.*/([^/]+)\.html $2.html?designer=$1 [NC,L]
I do have to add two almost duplicate rules this way though.